# Is an $L^1$ limit of convex functions convex?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f\in L_{loc}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is such that $f_n\in L_{loc}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are convex and converge to $f$ in $L_{loc}^1$. Is $f$ necessarily convex?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Since the functions $f_n$ are convex in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (see e.g. Rockafellar, *Convex Analysis*, Thms. 10.6 and 10.8).

The convexity of $f$ is now an easy consequence of the inequality
$$
f_n(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f_n(x) + (1-\lambda) f_n(y),
\qquad \forall n\in\mathbb{N},
$$
that holds for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\lambda\in [0,1]$.

Comment: I am struggling to see why convergence everywhere holds without a priori assuming that $f$ is continuous. In general $L^1$ convergence of continuous functions only implies pointwise convergence up to a nullset.

Comment: I have added a reference.

Comment: But the pointwise limit $g$ of $(f_n)$ is not necessarily equal to $f$ (only a.e.). Of course this is the best one can hope for, as one could always change $f$ on a null set and still have convergence in $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$.

Comment: @MaoWao: yes, of course. Here we are taking the continuous representative in the equivalence class.